# Insert html code after element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html document which looks like this:

```
...html code...
<ul id="my_ul">
...html code...
```

Using javascript I want to insert the html code below inside the document, immediately after `<ul id="my_ul">` :

```
<li><span>Some text</span><ul>
```

So far I have this, but not the expected results. Please, what am I doing wrong?

```
var para1 = document.createElement("li");
var para2 = document.createElement("span");
var node = document.createTextNode("Some text");
para2.appendChild(node);
var para3 = document.createElement("ul");
var element = document.getElementById("my_ul");
element.appendChild(para1);
element.appendChild(para2);
element.appendChild(para3);
```

Comment: last three lines should read element.parentNode.appendChild(para1); If you really want to append it AFTER ul not as last child of ul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want shorter code without creating objects for each html elements just do this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("my_ul");
var html = '<li><span>Some text</span></li>'; 
element.innerHTML = html + element.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("my_ul");

var li   = document.createElement("li");
var span = document.createElement("span");
var text = document.createTextNode("Some text");
span.appendChild(text);
li.appendChild(span);
ul.appendChild(li);
```

```html
<ul id="my_ul">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to do?

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/666nutmf/)

```
var para1 = document.createElement("li");
var para2 = document.createElement("span");
var node = document.createTextNode("Some text");
para2.appendChild(node);
para1.appendChild(para2);
element = document.getElementById("my_ul");
element.appendChild(para1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does this:

> ```
> element.appendChild(para1);
> ```

Make the list item a child of the original list

> ```
> element.appendChild(para2);
> ```

Make the span a child of the original list

> ```
> element.appendChild(para3);
> ```

Make the new list a child of the original list

---

You need to append each element to the element you want to be its parent instead of appending everything to the original list.

Replace `element` with the appropriate variable.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
var para1 = document.createElement("li");
var para2 = document.createElement("span");
var node = document.createTextNode("Some text");
para2.appendChild(node);
   
var element = document.getElementById("my_ul");
element.appendChild(para1);
para1.appendChild(para2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="my_ul">
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var ul = document.getElementById("my_ul");
var li = document.createElement("li");
var span = document.createElement("span");
var textNode = document.createTextNode("Some text");
span.appendChild(textNode);
li.appendChild(span);
ul.appendChild(li);
```

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but code without any explanation still does not make a good answer.

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure `document.createTextNode("<span>Some text</span>")` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: you are right. Separatly I have to create text node and li element.